# PIVOT SQL data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

I need to pivot data in SQL Server 2008. Can someone please give me some pointers to look around?

My Raw data looks like as:

[image]

```
create table #tbl (
ServiceDesc_2 varchar(20), ListCode_2 varchar(10), LongestWaitingDays_2 int, AvgWaitingDays_2 int, TotalPatientsWaiting_2 int);


insert #tbl 
    select 'XYZ - Left Side',   'Booked',   67, 16, 38
 union all 
    select  'XYZ - Left Side',  'UnBooked', 23, 6, 53
union all 
    select  'XYZ - Right Side', 'Booked',   14, 8, 2
union all 
    select  'XYZ - Right Side', 'UnBooked', 4, 3, 2
```

I am trying to achieve below:

[image]

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool, not the database itself. What you ask (merged cells) is better suited for a report engine. In SQL, you'd require functionality like `LAG()` to find what the previous cell looked like. That was introduced in later versions. SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported. In fact, the earliest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare your data with `cross apply` to multiply the rows in order to replicate the columns.

Then you can perform a conditional aggregation to obtain the desired results.

Here is a sample query that should work:

```
 ;with c as
    (
        select ServiceDesc_2,col,val as measures,ListCode_2,ord  
        from #tbl 
        cross apply 
        (
            values 
             ('LongestWaitingDays_2'  ,LongestWaitingDays_2  , 1)
            ,('AvgWaitingDays_2'      ,AvgWaitingDays_2      , 2)
            ,('TotalPatientsWaiting_2',TotalPatientsWaiting_2, 3)
        )
        CS (col,val,ord)
    )
select 
     ServiceDesc_2  
    ,col as Measures
    ,MAX(case when ListCode_2='UnBooked' then measures else null end) as UnBooked
    ,MAX(case when ListCode_2='Booked'   then measures else null end) as Booked
from c
group by ServiceDesc_2, col
order by ServiceDesc_2, max(ord)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrea for the help. I have not used Cross apply before. I am getting an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.' I am copying the exact code as you wrote earlier. Can you help?

Comment: @Namish VALUES (or Table Value Constructor) was introduced in SQL Server 2008, so you should have no problems using it. Please check the compatibility level of your DB (it is a SQL Server 2008, so it should be 100)